# Can I override an overload of an operator and return a different type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, polymorphism, covariance, virtual-functions

```
class A{
  public: 
    virtual char &operator[](int);
  protected:
    ..
};
class B:A{
  public:
    A* &operator[](int);
  protected:
}
```

Can I change the return type when I overload an overload of an operator?

thanks!

**//EDIT**
Okay, so now that we established that this wont work how can I build a work around?

Lets say I have classes A,B,C, and D.

```
class A{
  public: 
  private:
    char &operator[](int);
  protected:
    ..
};
class B:A{
  public: 
    virtual char &operator[](int);
};
class C: A{
  public:
  private:
    A::&operator[](int);
}
class D: A{
  public:
  private:
     A::&operator[](int);
}
```

Can I do something like this? If so is this the correct syntax?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with the new example.  What is _the problem_ that you are trying to solve?  (Perhaps there is a different, potentially better way to solve it!)

Comment: Okay in a nutshell as best as I can describe it: I have a Class called Sequence. Alot of operations are the same across two sub classes one is called GeneSeqs and one is called GenomeSeq. The key difference between these two classes is that GeneSeqs has a collection of Sequences as its basic data. So when I use the [int] operator I want to get a refrence to the sub sequence that is part of GeneSeqs, but for Sequence I want the [int] operator to return a character.

Comment: But in what circumstances do you want to call `operator[]` on a pointer/reference-to-`Sequence` that actually contains a `GeneSeq`?  What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: When I want to get back the specific nucleotide within the sequence. I know its a bit redundant but it helps make the code more readable. 


Really I am just curious to see if there is a way to do this so I can learn. So far it seems to me that its taboo to change return types between inherited member functions -- so I should avoid it.Am I correct? 

Just saw your edit. That will never happen. GeneSeq contains Sequence objects, never the other way around.

Comment: By "contains" I mean "points at" or "refers to"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that a polymorphic function can't return different types in different classes isn't because someone on the C++ committee decided that it was "taboo", but because any code that used that function's return value couldn't compile.

By creating an inheritance heirarchy, you're able to access derived objects through a base pointer or reference:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual char operator[](int);
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual char operator[](int);
};

A *a;

std::cout << "Do you want to make an A or a B?";

char type;
std::cin >> type;

if (type == 'A')
    a = new A();
else
    a = new B();

char c = (*a)[0];
```

Note that on the last line, the compiler won't know what type of object `a` is pointing to, since that's determined at runtime.  This is fine, because no matter what type of object `a` is pointing to, `operator[]` is still going to return a character.  But what if that operator were allowed to return a different type in class `B`?

```
class Sequence
{
    ...
};

class A
{
public:
    virtual char operator[](int);
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual Sequence operator[](int);
};

A *a = new B();
char c = (*a)[0];
```

Obviously, that last line makes no sense when `a` is an object of type `B`.  In that case, you're trying to assign a `Sequence` to a character.  Likewise, `Sequence c = (*a)[0];` wouldn't make sense if `a` were an object of type `A`.

Comment: Well, you never know; Stroustrup may have put that rule in after a long night of drinking only to find afterwards that it was a really good idea ;-)

Comment: Thank you man! Appreciate that. Very thorough answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not like this, no.

The return type of an override must be either

- the same type as the return type of the virtual function being overridden, or
- a derived class of the return type of the virtual function being overridden (this is called a "covariant return type").

So, if a virtual `A::operator[]` returned an `A*`, then a `B::operator[]` override could return a `B*`.

Comment: Ah, but thats not the case. Then is there a work around where I can declare the overloaded [] to be private in class A, and then lets say class C,D, and E need it, can I inherit it in a non polymorphic fashion?

Comment: @yShalabi:  I don't understand what you are asking.  Would you clarify?  (It's probably best if you edit the question and give another example).

Comment: @yShalabi: If you don't want it to be polymorphic, then why declare it `virtual` in the base class?

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth I do want it polymorphic, it is just one class needs this operator in another functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to make `A` a member of classes `C` and `D` rather than a base class.  Since `C` and `D` need a different signature for a public method, they're clearly not equivalent to an `A` in every context, so trying to use inheritance here really makes no sense.

Comment: C and D need the same signature, B needs a different one.

Answer (score 0):

OK looking at your last comment about Sequence (`A`), GeneSequence (`B`) and GenomeSequence (`C`)

you want the operator to sometimes return a `char`, and sometimes return a `Sequence`

well then, as you can see, it is incorrect for the superclass `A` to declare the type of `&operator []` as `char`.

It should use a **template** as a type parameter, to specify whether it is a collection of `char`s or `Sequence`s, right?